# Experience Editor issue after upgrading to Sitecore 9.3

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

After upgrading to Sitecore 9.3 getting below error in Experience Editor:-

```
sitecore Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.Pipelines.GetChromeData.GetChromeDataProcessor
```

We are using Glass Mapper

Comment: Do a beyond compare to a vanilla bin/config vs yours. It sounds like your deployment pushed some older stuff back into the site.

Comment: Or removed obsolete code is used, see crosspost https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/10802  the constructor public GetChromeDataProcessor() is removed in Sitecore 9.3

Comment: Which version of Glassmapper are you using? A compatible version has not been released yet, it is still in beta.

Comment: I'm also facing similar issue. But In my case, I installed new Sitecore 9.3 instance and Horizon 9.3. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23429/sitecore-horizon-method-not-found-void-sitecore-pipelines-getchromedata-getc

Comment: @Deve, I tested with vanilla version of Sitecore 9.3 with Glass Mapper Glass.Mapper.Sc.92 (5.5.28) version. I am facing similar issue while testing with Horizon which is similar as Experience Editor. Then I removed glass mapper then it is working fine.

Comment: There is a beta version of glass that fixes this

Comment: The first alpha package has just been released for sitecore 9.3 support https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glass.Mapper.Sc.93

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore.Pipelines.GetChromeData.GetChromeDataProcessor abstract class is available in 9.3 and in higher and lower versions as well.

But some methods were deprecated in lower versions and were removed in higher versions.

Usually, such methods and classes are marked as Obsolete with suggestions on what to use instead, you'll be able to see such warnings during the build. But if you're jumping a few major versions ahead you might lose these suggestions and you'll see a compilation error.

But if you didn't get this issue during solution build (and got this in runtime) means that you most likely forgot to update references to Sitecore assemblies/NuGet packages to the newer 9.3 version in your solution.

Note, that all 3d party modules/assemblies/packages should be compatible with the 9.3 version as well to avoid such situations.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue while testing with vanilla version of Sitecore 9.3 with "Glass.Mapper.Sc.93 -Version 5.6.157-alpha" version. I received below reply from Mike Edwards regarding this issue. Now Experience editor is working fine for me.

[image]

Comment: that still breaks for me. it only works if I remove the whole 'processor' line